# Can I know if a user downvotes competing answers to gain better position for his own answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have recently seen some suspicious behaviour in fast simple answers:

1. I answer a question in first few minutes
2. Answer gets one fast upvote
3. A new answer with same (or really similar) code appears
4. A downvote appears on my answer
5. The new answer gets better position to receive upvotes due to activity
6. *(Optional)* Downvote on my answer is removed.

So:

1. There is a way to know if the user who has posted the new answer has downvoted my answer? (not sure if -1 appears in user profile).
2. Can I flag this behaviour somehow?
3. Should questions with 0 up/down votes, be in better position than those with 0 (but with no up/down votes)?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24165/is-tactical-down-voting-ever-valid, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/does-reducing-the-window-to-change-votes-really-solve-the-tactical-downvoting-pr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. No.  Downvotes are anonymous by design.
2. No.  Users are free to vote on posts that they have answered.  You have no way to prove that it's even that person voting, and even if you did, you have no way of knowing that they aren't voting because they think the answer is a bad answer.
3. Answers with the same score are ranked equally, regardless of how many actual upvotes they have (although answers with the same score and posted close together are randomized on every page load, since of course it's not like they can be side by side, which is why his may well have been above yours when you reloaded the page).

Comment: Yeah there are too many legitimate reasons for downvotes that trying to control them would be way too hard.  And against the whole idea of SO.  Just improve your answer to make it even better and that will attract more upvotes over time.